# Aurelia binding for custom elements

Tags: typescript, aurelia

currently I'm facing the following challange using aurelia:

Following my **user-model**:

```
export class User{
    @bindable name: string;
    @bindable address: Address;
```

I have a layout view-model including a form:

**Parent UserRegistration JS**

```
export class UserRegistration{
    @bindable user: User

    public registerUser(){
        let address = this.user.address;
        //register user and so on ...
    }
}
```

**Parent UserRegistration template**

```
<template>
    <require from="user-address"></require>    

    <form id="user-registration-form" submit.delegate="registerUser()>
        <user-adress user.bind="user"></user>
    </form>
</template>
```

and then I have a custom-element:

**CustomElement userAddress JS**

```
@customElement('userAddress')
@autoinject
export class userAddress{
      @bindable user: User;
}
```

**CustomElement userAddress template:**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" id="street-name" value.bind="user.address.streetname" />
</template>
```

Now I want, that clicking on submit, the information from custom-element "user-address" are taken over into the layout view-model so that I can use it in "registerUser()".

Can anyone tell me, how I can get that working? Currently, I only get a "undefined" in parent view-model.

Comment: There are a few typo's in your code, for example `<user-adress>` (should be `<user-address>`). Are these in your code as well or did you copy them to SO wrong?

Comment: FYI you can actually set the default binding mode on a bindable (just pass arguments to the decorator). This enables you to keep in the spirit of Aurelia and use the expected convention for `bind` instead of being explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default binding mode for this
`<user-adress user.bind="user"></user>`
will be one-way..

you have to change it to
`<user-adress user.two-way="user"></user>`

that should do

to keep in touch with aurelia community, join the aurelia forums https://discourse.aurelia.io/
and gitter channel https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss

Answer (score 4):

You need to use two-way binding. Your current situation, using `user.bind` only binds one-way, meaning that if you edit the binding in the child it will not update in the parent.

If you bind the value like so:

```
<user-address user.two-way="user"></user>
```

Any changes that you make to the `user` in the `user-address` element will also update the `user` in the parent viewmodel.

Comment: nice timing (-:

Comment: Only 32 seconds off ;-)